# df.loc filtering doesn't work with None values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Why does this filtering not work when the filter is `Project ID` == None? I also noticed `is None` rather than `== None` returns  `KeyError: False`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Project1', 'CT', 800], [None, 3, 1000], ['Project3', 'CA', 20]], columns=['Project ID', 'State', 'Cost'])

print df.loc[df['Project ID'] == 'Project1'].values
print df.loc[df['Project ID'] == None].values
```

output:

```
[['Project1' 'CT' 800L]]
[]
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `isnull` for this:

```
In [3]:

df[df['Project ID'].isnull()]
Out[3]:
  Project ID State  Cost
1       None     3  1000
```

Or use `apply`:

```
In [5]:

df.loc[df['Project ID'].apply(lambda x: x is None)]
Out[5]:
  Project ID State  Cost
1       None     3  1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate, it doesn't work because `pandas` use `np.nan`, and:

```
print np.nan == np.nan   # False
print np.nan == None     # False
print np.isnan(np.nan)   # True
```